# "Remember password" option [C#]

Tags: c#, passwords, save

i need to implement a "Remember password" option in my program, it works with client-server protocols that REQUIRE the entire password to be passed in the loggin process, not only Hashes, so i need to store the entire password locally. I searched all over the place but i found no conclusive answer or no answer at all. But since Email clients, Internet Browsers, IM clients do it, it shouldn't be impossible...

so, what's the best method?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should be more specific, is it asp.net or winform?

Comment: So what's the problem exactly ? can't you just save the password to a file ?

Comment: yes, save password to a file, but dont forget to encrypt it with another password.. wait..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Just dont do it.  No matter how good your security *not* *storing* *passwords* is still better.

2) If you **have** to do it, [consider windows secure storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx)

Comment: Point 1 is a /bit/ like saying "Don't take your keys out of your house in case you lose them"

Comment: Actually, I agree 100% with point 1. Once you know how easy it is to bypass all of the measures mentioned as answers to this question, you'll realize the wisdom of that point.

Comment: I'm very well aware of it, but there's a connivence/security trade off. I wouldn't store my banking passwords, but I would store my IM passwords.

Comment: But, if i secure the data with DPAPI it will be available to all processes running in my Loggon right? Can Windows return the data only to a specific process (through app's hash verification or something)?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the CredentialsUI.  [There's an article on MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/indonesia/msdn/credmgmt.aspx) explaining how to use it in .NET.

I'm fairly sure it's what's used by modern email clients, Internet Browsers etc.  It provides an option to save your credentials, encrypted using DPAPI.

I've created a C# wrapper class that makes it easy to use from managed apps.